# CS:GO not ranking me up

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

My current rank is Nova Master (Nova 4) and I've won 6 games straight. Also was I either 1st or 2nd in my team.

After that, I tied one time, and won 4 games in a row. I still haven't ranked to Master Guardian.

What's keeping me from ranking up? I've been playing with a friend who won 4 (from start of Nova 4 to end) and ranked. Also was he below me most of the times.

Comment: Play, play, play and don't question. You will rank up eventually.

Comment: Are you on a server with VAC disabled?

Comment: @RobertRose No no no, not at all. It's 'the' legit valve/steam CS:GO competitive matchmaking.